# JobScheduler Service stops when it is clear from recent and does start again when the setPeriodic timeout

Tags: android, android-service, job-scheduling

I am creating an app in which I start a **JobService** service in MainActivity. When the app is in foreground the app works as expected but when I cleared the app from recent apps, the service doesn't responds and even **onStopJob** is not called. The service is not even execute after the **setPeriodic(1000*60*15)** time is expired.
In onStartJob method, I create a seperate Thread and perform some network and database tasks. For network activities I use JSOUP library.

Here is code:
This function is called in **MainActivity**:

```
private void startJobScheduler() {
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MyJobService.class);
    JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(123, componentName)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
            .setPeriodic(1000 * 60 * 15)
            .build();
    JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    if (scheduler != null) {
        scheduler.schedule(info);
    }
}
```

JobService code:

```
 @Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.d("TAG", "Job started");
    doBackgroundWork(params);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.d("TAG", "Job stopped");
    isCancelled = true;
    return false;
}
private void doBackgroundWork(final JobParameters params) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("TAG", "Job thread started");
            Document document;
            boolean flag;
            SarkariPage sarkariPage;
            ArrayList<Anchor> anchorList;
            NotificationCheckerDatabase checkerDatabase = new NotificationCheckerDatabase(MyJobService.this);
            NotificationDatabaseHelper notificationDatabaseHelper = new NotificationDatabaseHelper(MyJobService.this);
            for (final Anchor anchor : myanchors) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Job anchor " + anchor.getText());
                flag = false;
                if (isCancelled) {
                    return;
                }
                initiate(anchor);
                try {
                    if ((document = Jsoup.connect(anchor.getHref()).userAgent("Mozilla").get()) != null) {
                        sarkariPage = new SarkariPage(MyJobService.this, document);
                        anchorList = sarkariPage.getAnchors();

                        if (checkerDatabase.getJobsCount(LATEST) == 0) {
                            for (Anchor a : anchorList) {
                                checkerDatabase.insertJob(LATEST, a.getText(), a.getHref());
                            }
                        } else {
                            for (Anchor a1 : anchorList) {
                                if (!checkerDatabase.isJobExists(LATEST, a1.getText(), a1.getHref())) {
                                    flag = true;
                                    sendNotification(a1.getText(), a1.getHref());
                                    notificationDatabaseHelper.insertJob(a1.getText(), a1.getHref());
                                }
                            }
                            if (flag) {
                                checkerDatabase.deleteAllJob(LATEST);
                                for (Anchor a : anchorList) {
                                    checkerDatabase.insertJob(LATEST, a.getText(), a.getHref());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Log.d("TAG", "Job finished");
            jobFinished(params, false);
        }
    });
    t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: What's your minSdk? and in which api you are testing?

Comment: minSdk = 21. No idea about testing api.

Comment: You don't know the api of the device/emulator in which you are testing your code?

Comment: I am testing in real devices having marshmallow(ASUS) and nougat(REDMI). But the behavior is same in both the devices.

Comment: Any thread or any service get stuck after removing from recent apps.

Comment: JobScheduler should run without any trouble unless the app is force stopped. Sometimes some custom OS actually force stop apps when removed from task, please check if REDMI ASUS actually does that

Comment: Ok I will check that. One another problem is that after the setPeriodic time is elapsed, the service doesn't execute. It execute only when the app is in foreground after timeout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177429/discussion-between-mrah-and-mia).

Comment: Try using Firebase Job Dispatcher